# Back to My Mac not working in school network

Tags: networking, mac, firewall, afp

I can't connect to my Back to My Mac shared Airport Disk while under my school's firewall. I tried using a VPN to bypass the firewall, but from what I can find the VPN uses the same port as BTMM and therefore cannot be used simultaneously. Is there a better way to get past this port blocking? It seems like there should be a way to use port 80 or something, but have it access port 443, 4500, etc. on the Airport Drive at my house.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be that you go to your Schools Network Administrator and declare him your Situation and Ask him for Assistance. If you just try to do Things yourself in a Foreign Network they may interpret this as a Security Breach and maybe they also initiate legal action against you.

Comment: I'm sure this would move the situation forward, but like I'm not going to do it so...